# How to get key fingerprint for SFTP from private key?

Tags: .net, sftp, public-key, winscp, winscp-net

As I am working on a .NET C# project which uses WinSCP .NET assembly, for SFTP password less connection. By far I have made an UI where we have to provide SSH key fingerprint, paraphrase, and path of `.ppk` file.

My question is that, is there any way to get "SSH key fingerprint" automatically through code, if the user gives its `.ppk` file path only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.ppk` is a key pair of your account and you specify that using the [`SessionOptions.SshPrivateKeyPath`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#sshprivatekeypath).

While the host key for [`SessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#sshhostkeyfingerprint) is for key pair of the server (= host). It's not a public key of your key pair.

These key pairs have nothing in common. You cannot extract one from another.

For details, see [Understanding SSH key pairs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys).

See also [Where do I get SSH host key fingerprint to authorize the server?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey)

---

If you want to allow the user to verify the host key manually, use the [`Session.ScanFingerprint` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_scanfingerprint) to retrieve the fingerprint for verification. Once verified, assign the verified fingerprint to the `SessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint`.

For an example, see [Implementing SSH host key cache (known hosts)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_known_hosts).